# Reference a block that was built using a loop

Tags: terraform

My initial working code looks like this

First I reserver IPs

```
resource "google_compute_address" "ecmp-1" {
  name         = "nat-ecmp-1"
  address      = "10.8.2.6"
}

resource "google_compute_address" "ecmp-2" {
  name         = "nat-ecmp-2"
  address      = "10.8.2.7"
}
```

Then I created instance templates and attach the IPs to them

```
resource "google_compute_instance_template" "template-1" {
  name        = "ecmp-1"
  # OMITED EXTRA 
  network_interface {
    # OMITED EXTRA
    network_ip = google_compute_address.ecmp-1.address
  }
}

resource "google_compute_instance_template" "template-2" {
  name        = "ecmp-2"
  # OMITED EXTRA 
  network_interface {
    # OMITED EXTRA
    network_ip = google_compute_address.ecmp-2.address
  }
}
```

And then I create instance groups out of those templates

```
resource "google_compute_region_instance_group_manager" "nstance-1" {
  name = "instance-1"

  version {
    instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.template-1.self_link
  }
  target_size  = 1
}

resource "google_compute_region_instance_group_manager" "instance-2" {
  name = "instance-2"

  version {
    instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.template-2.self_link
  }
  target_size  = 1
}
```

The above code works well but if I had ALOT of instance groups to make, the code would get bloated. For this I am now using maps and `for_each`

My new code for IPs and for the instance group template looks like

```
resource "google_compute_address" "reservered-ips" {
  for_each = var.nat_ecmp_frontend_reserved_ips

  name         = each.key
  subnetwork   = "egress-ingress"
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  address      = each.value
}

resource "google_compute_instance_template" "template-1" {
  for_each = var.nat_ecmp_frontend_reserved_ips

  name        = each.key
  # OMITED EXTRA 
  network_interface {
    # OMITED EXTRA
    network_ip = google_compute_address.reservered-ips[each.key].address
  }
}
```

Now the next step is to create an instance group out of the above 2 templates created using a `for_each` loop.

So when declaring this

```
resource "google_compute_region_instance_group_manager" "instances" {
  for_each = var.nat_ecmp_frontend_reserved_ips

  name = each.key

  version {
    instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.<? ? ? ? ?>
  }
  target_size  = 1
}
```

How can I loop and reference `instance_template` ? Is there some dynamic way of doing that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `resource` block with `for_each` set appears as a map value when referenced, so your `google_compute_instance_template.template-1` result will be a map whose keys match the keys from `var.nat_ecmp_frontend_reserved_ips`.

It looks like the intent you want to describe here is "create one instance group manager per instance template", which we can represent concisely by using the `google_compute_instance_template.template-1` map as the `for_each` of the second resource, like this:

```
resource "google_compute_region_instance_group_manager" "instances" {
  for_each = google_compute_instance_template.template-1

  name         = each.key
  target_size  = 1

  version {
    instance_template = each.value.id
  }
}
```

By setting `for_each` to `google_compute_instance_template.template-1` instead of `var.nat_ecmp_frontend_reserved_ips`, we express more directly the intent that there should be one group manager per template. But it also has the more practical benefit that `each.value` inside that block refers to each of the `google_compute_instance_template` objects, and so we can use `each.value.id` to obtain the id of the object associated with `each.key`.